# Set SQL column type as varchar(50), only accepts integers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, varchar

As the titles says, I created a table Where one column is the type varchar(50), however it rejects INSERT statements where the first value is a string:

*Table Creation:*

```
CREATE TABLE Fiddy(Lname varchar(50),
-> Height int,
-> Width int,
-> Gas int);
```

*Insert attempt*

```
insert into Fiddy VALUES(Smith, 54, 43, 1);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Smith' in 'field list'
```

*Insert attempt*

```
insert into Fiddy values (4, 5, 5, 6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

*Select **

```
select * from Fiddy;
+-------+--------+-------+------+
| Lname | Height | Width | Gas  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+
| 4     |      5 |     5 |    6 |
+-------+--------+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hint: *values* are never used as table/column *identifiers* in SQL syntax. Inserting an integer works because 1) an integer is/represents a *value*; and 2) the integer is coerced as needed.

Answer (score 9):

Basic MySQL. Strings must be enclosed in single quotes. Otherwise it is assumed you are referring to a column name.

```
insert into Fiddy VALUES(Smith, 54, 43, 1); -- The column "Smith" is assumed.
```

should be

```
insert into Fiddy VALUES('Smith', 54, 43, 1); -- The string "Smith" is used.
```

Comment: Wow. Today is not my day to be awake. Thank you.

Comment: @JamesRoberts . . . This appears to be the correct answer.  You should accept it.